# Merging text files with different character encodings

Tags: windows, text, unicode, cmd, character-encoding

I am trying to merge the content of text files in a directory into one text file.

Some text files are encoded in ANSI, some in UTF-8 and some in UTF-8 with BOM and other character encodings.

I tried to merge with type and copy commands but the result file would contain strange characters. "ö", for example, becomes "Ã¶". Other European/accented letters are also messed up. Also, there are lines that begin with "ï»¿" which after some investigation is actually the invisible BOM character.

How can I merge these text files into one retaining their readable form? I am open to suggestions beside Windows CMD.

Answer (score 2):

You can't blindly merge the files.  If you know which files are which encodings, then you can use a tool to re-code them each to a common representation such as UTF-8 before merging.  For example, in Python 3.x, this will concatenate four files of various encodings into a common UTF-8-encoded file (untested):

```
#!python3

files = [('file1.txt','cp1252'),
         ('file2.txt','utf8'),
         ('file3.txt','utf-8-sig'),
         ('file4.txt','chinese')]

with open('output.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as out:
    for filename,encoding in files:
        with open(filename,encoding=encoding) as f:
            out.write(f.read())
```